# Eliminating characters from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am reading from a file, and some of the data is comming in like this

```
"\"ZIP\""
```

so when i try to assign it its causing errors, i want to get rid off the extra `\"`, so if I assign it to as string like

```
string s = data[1].ToString();
```

what `s` is `"\"ZIP\""`

i just want it to be "ZIP", i tried:

```
string s = data[1].ToString().replace("\\\"","");
```

but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `data.Replace("\"", "")` work?

Comment: I suspect the value is actually "ZIP" and when you dump the contents the double quotes are being escaped, which is why the comment above probably works.

Comment: You say "it is causing errors", but what errors? Also, what is `s.Length` after this assigment?

Comment: `"\"ZIP\""` I think you see this type of string when debugging mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try:

```
var result = "\"ZIP\"".Replace("\"", "");
```

Or:

```
 var result = "\"ZIP\"".Trim('"');
```

Answer (score 1):

String.Trim could be used with an array of char to remove from start and end of a string

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '"', '\\'};
string s = data[1].ToString().Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the escape characters in the string by split and create new string. You can include as many characters in escape sequence array as you want.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string[] parts = inputString.Split(new char[] {'"'};
 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int size = parts.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", parts[i]);= 

string strWithoutEscape = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data[1].toString().replace("\\\"", "");
```

Notice that the function is case-sensitive, so using ToString would fail.